# Why my camera is not taking photos? expo-camera

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why my camera is not taking photos? expo-camera? when I test this in my emulator android then it was taking photos and logging its value but when i test and try to take a photo on a real device android then it was not taking photos and not logging any value does anyone knows how can I fix this problem to make this work? my camera permission is  granted

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { firebase } from '../../Storage/Firebase/config';

export default function CameraPage({ navigation }) {

  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.front);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  const handleTakePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();

      if (!photo.cancelled) {
        const response = await fetch(photo.uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const filename = photo.uri.substring(photo.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename);
        const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
        const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log(url)
        navigation.navigate('addpost', { post: url });
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} ref={cameraRef}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              alignSelf: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              width: 90,
              height: 90,
              borderRadius: 500,
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              marginTop: '150%',
              marginLeft: '35%',
              borderColor: '#fff',
              borderWidth: 4,
            }}
            onPress={handleTakePicture}
          >
            <View style={{ opacity: 0.5, }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do either of these two trigger - `hasPermission === null` , `hasPermission === false` ? Also, I'd expand your `if(!photo.cancelled)` with an `} else { alert("cancelled"); }`, and maybe replace the `console.log(url)` with an `alert(url)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo-camera';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { firebase } from '../../Storage/Firebase/config';

export default function CameraPage({ navigation }) {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.front);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>No access to camera</Text>
        <Button title='Grant Permission' onPress={getPermission} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  const handleTakePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();

      if (!photo.cancelled) {
        const response = await fetch(photo.uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const filename = photo.uri.substring(photo.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename);
        const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
        const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log(url)
        navigation.navigate('addpost', { post: url });
      }
    }
  }
  
  const getPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} ref={cameraRef}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              alignSelf: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              width: 90,
              height: 90,
              borderRadius: 500,
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              marginTop: '150%',
              marginLeft: '35%',
              borderColor: '#fff',
              borderWidth: 4,
            }}
            onPress={handleTakePicture}
          >
            <View style={{ opacity: 0.5, }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Also, Make sure that the app has been granted the necessary permissions to access the camera on the device. You can check this by going to the device's settings and verifying that the app has been granted camera permissions.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoCamera.Permissions.askAsync')

Comment: @Jack Try to update your expo-camera package to the latest version if not installed then install: expo install expo-camera

Comment: yes but i don't need the user to click a button for permission. how can i do that it directly asks the user permission for the camera as i did in my code. can you edit out your answer also my expo-camera package is latest

Comment: @Jack Replace paste useEffect in your code to the code I provided. It should automatically ask for permission

Comment: not working TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoCamera.Permissions.askAsync')